# Ho to read the number of columns (colspan) used by a single table cell with python-docx

Tags: python, cell, python-docx

I am trying to read a table with multiple row and col spans with python-docx.
How can I determine if the current cell which I read is spanned across 1,2,... cells.

Example:

```
|----------------------------------|
|This cell spans across            | -> spans across 3 cells
|----------------------------------|
| cell A    | cell B     | cell C  |
| cell spans acorss      |  cell D |  -> spans across 2 cells
```

Comment: Does the following help? (look for `def _cells(self):`): https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/docx/table.html#_Cell  _A sequence of |_Cell| objects, one for each cell of the layout grid. **If the table contains a span, one or more |_Cell| object references
        are repeated.**_

Answer (score 1):

These values are only available on the top-left cell of a merged region. But you can access them using:

```
cell._tc.grid_span  # --- optional int number of columns this cell spans ---
cell._tc.vMerge     # --- optional int number of rows this cell spans ---
```

A value of `None` for either of these indicates there is no merge in that direction.

In `python-docx`, each cell is "addressed" by its *grid* coordinates, which is basically the shape of the table *before* any merging. So you can access a merged cell with as many "addresses" as the merge cell contains. For example, a 2 x 2 merge at the top left of a 3 x 3 table would be accessed by row/col coordinates (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0) and (1, 1). Each of these would refer to the same cell.

Consequently, the `.grid_span` and `.vMerge` properties are accessible in any merged cell, regardless of how you got there.

Comment: Thx. That helps a lot. As always a good answer leads to the next question :)

Comment: the property vMerge  gives back a value of "restart" for a cell that spans across rows, not the number. Is there a way to get the nuerical value or do I need to calculate this by myself?

Comment: These are the methods/properties on `._tc` you have available. Maybe `tc.bottom - tc.top`. https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/oxml/table.py#L369

Comment: @StefanHock Welcome to StackOverflow :) Don't neglect to accept a correct answer. That's how you show appreciation for the respondent taking the time to answer.